# Symfony choice field type reports "This value is not valid" when submitting an invalid option. How do I change this?

Tags: symfony, choicefield

I've noticed that when using the Symfony 2.3 choice field type, if I try to submit an invalid option (by manually changing the value of an option), symfony reports a form error on that field that says "This value is not valid".

However, I see no option to change this message in the choice field type class. I have not validation constraints set up for this field either.

Where is this error message coming from, and how do I change it?

Comment: Yoy might need to use form event listeners if you change choice fields browser-side (i.e. AJAX). Please see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The sentence "The value is not valid" is the default error message which results of a form field transformation failure. This error message is related to each field in case of a data transformer failed (in your case it seems you try to send an invalid choice value). If you want to override it, you can use the `invalid_message` & `invalid_message_parameters` form type options.

I can't find the official documentation of this property right now but you can take a look to this for more details: [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Type/FormTypeValidatorExtension.php#L66-L67)

Comment: Here's the link to *invalid_message* property doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#invalid-message
It is inherited from the Form Type, since v2.3

Answer (score 2):

The message is coming from the choice constraint, not the choice field type class.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html

The **message** option can be overridden with your own message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have not setup any validation constraints for the entity class so I doubt that it is stemming from that.

Answer (score -1):

You can get value of parameter to check is valid after set value valid or null for it.

Get value of field after submit form

```
   $name = $request->request->get('name');
```

Check it is not valid after set value valid for it

```
if (empty($name)) {
  $request->request->set('name', 'your name');
}
```